# Iframe breaks responsiveness

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following template in iframe: http://vho_pfodox_1811.vh.parking.ru/templates/resume

On small devices it works not properly, but without iframe it looks ok. How can I make this work in iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have this metadata tag in the head of the site/iframe HTML?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: O, thank you, this changes everything))

Answer (score 0):

On small devices as the width and the height of the device changes you need to follow a different design technique called Responsive Web Design(RWD) ,where the components of your web page can be made to fit to the screen size.

For your iframe ,in css

```
iframe
{
  width:(your own dimension)%;
  height:(your own dimension)%;
  margin:(your own dimension)%;
}
```

and in your HTML source add this meta tag inside the head tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Note : For making your iframe responsive you need to specify your dimensions only in % and not in other units like px,in or em